# Does this mean that Java is not free any more?

Tags: java, commercial-application

> You may not:
>
> - Use the Programs for any data processing or any commercial, production, or internal business purposes other than developing, testing, prototyping, and demonstrating your Application;
>
> ~ [Oracle Technology Network License Agreement for Oracle Java SE](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/javase-license.html) ~

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question, not a technical question.

Comment: The Oracle JDK is not the only Java development kit. Either you pay Oracle to use it in production, or you use one of the JDKs from a different vendor, eg OpenJDK, Azul, RedHat, IBM, AdoptOpenJDK and others. See also [Do not fall into Oracle's Java 11 trap](https://blog.joda.org/2018/09/do-not-fall-into-oracles-java-11-trap.html) and [Java is still available at zero-cost](https://blog.joda.org/2018/08/java-is-still-available-at-zero-cost.html)